# Ionic Angular HTML carrying over through multiple routing pages

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

So I am working on an Ionic Angular App & I chose the preset design "Shapes" when creating the app. 
Started working on routing in the App and the HTML in the app.component.html is carrying over through all routing pages.
I have no clue what's causing this.
Is it possible to turn this off in certain routing pages?

```
<ion-tab-bar slot="bottom" >

  <button ion-button  class="button-size" routerLink="home" routerDirection="root" >
    <ion-icon name="home" class="medium"></ion-icon>
    <ion-label>
      <br>Home
    </ion-label>
  </button>

  <button ion-button class="button-size" routerLink="statistics" routerDirection="root">
    <ion-icon name="stats" class="medium"></ion-icon>
    <ion-label>
      <br>Statistics
    </ion-label>
  </button>

  <button ion-button class="button-size" routerLink="routines" routerDirection="root">
    <ion-icon name="git-compare" class="medium"></ion-icon>
    <ion-label>
      <br>Routines
    </ion-label>
  </button>

  <button ion-button  class="button-size" routerLink="settings" routerDirection="root">
    <ion-icon name="settings" class="medium"></ion-icon>
    <ion-label>
      <br>Settings
    </ion-label>
  </button>


</ion-tab-bar>
```

this is my tool bar in app.component.html and it's appearing on all routing pages.

Comment: I can't understand the problem. Please be clear about the issue or post some screenshots.

Comment: The html in app.component.html is appearing on all routing pages. I would like to know how to remove this feature.

Comment: It is designed to work that way. Because App.component is the base module of all pages.

Answer (score 0):

app.component.html is the main component of the Ionic Apps. All the pages are added/removed over this main component. So, if you put any HTML inside this file, it will be available throughout the app. 
You can use `*ngIf directive` if you want to show/hide some HTML in certain pages/ components.

You can use `Router.url` to get the URL of the current page which can be used to check whether to show a `<div>` in that page or not.

Eg:
**In app.component.html:** This will show the following div in all the pages except in login page

```
<div #mySplashAnimation *ngIf="router.url!='login'">

...
</div>
```

**In app.component.ts:** Inject Router.

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

  ...

    constructor(public router:Router)
    {
     ...
    }
```

Comment: What is #mySplashAnimation. I still don't know what's causing this to happen.

Comment: It is just an Id. You can ignore it. I suggest you to read out the ionic documentation and ionic lifecycle to understand how Ionic apps gets loaded. https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/your-first-app